# Converting an PLSQL select statement into a update

Tags: plsql

Guys I have such a problem.

I know how to write a good select statement but I have no idea how to turn it into a corresponding update.

Im still learning plsql

Here is my select

```
select * --count(*) 
from POLISY_OT ot
  join polisy p on p.poli_id = ot.ot_poli_id
  join sou.rai_skl rs on rs.ot_id = ot.ot_id
where ot_under_promil = 0 
  and ot_skladka_rok <> ot_skladka_netto_rok 
  and ot_rodzaj_um = 'OP' 
  and ot_rodzaj = 'D'
  and ot_produkt_id = 17
  and p.poli_status in ('AK', 'CZ')
  and rs.skl_roczna = ot.ot_skladka_rok;
```

now I would like to wrap it up with an update and create something like this

```
update (
  select * --count(*) 
  from POLISY_OT ot
    join polisy p on p.poli_id = ot.ot_poli_id
    join sou.rai_skl rs on rs.ot_id = ot.ot_id
  where ot_under_promil = 0 
    and ot_skladka_rok <> ot_skladka_netto_rok 
    and ot_rodzaj_um = 'OP' 
    and ot_rodzaj = 'D'
    and ot_produkt_id = 17
    and p.poli_status in ('AK', 'CZ')
    and rs.skl_roczna = ot.ot_skladka_rok)
  set ot_skladka_rok = ot_skladka_netto_rok;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I really hope you aren't a student asking for homework help.  That **really** bugs me.

On the assumption it's not, it's a little hard to tell exactly which columns belong to which tables, given that you didn't include the table aliases throughout.

I read this as that you wanted to update a column based on the value in another table, restricting the table updates to records that match a third table).

So I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE polisy_ot ot
   SET ot_skladka_rok =
       (SELECT ot_skladka_netto_rok
          FROM sou.rai_skl rs
         WHERE rs.ot_id = ot.ot_id
           AND rs.skl_roczna = ot.ot_skladka_rok)
 WHERE ot_under_promil = 0
   AND ot_skladka_rok <> ot_skladka_netto_rok
   AND ot_rodzaj_um = 'OP'
   AND ot_rodzaj = 'D'
   AND ot_produkt_id = 17
   AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL
          FROM polisy p
         WHERE p.poli_id = ot.ot_poli_id
           AND p.poli_status IN ('AK', 'CZ'))
```

Good luck,

Stew

Comment: Thank you so much. I dont want to take advantage of anybody I just want to learn something :)

Comment: So this "and exist" is the way how you walked around the fact we cant  use a join statement at this point right? Nice.

Comment: Glad this worked for you.  Please mark my answer as correct and your question answered, so I can get the reputation credit.